# Stopping python using ctrl+c

Tags: python

I have a python script that uses threads and makes lots of HTTP requests. I think what's happening is that while a HTTP request (using urllib2) is reading, it's blocking and not responding to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to stop the program. Is there any way around this?

Comment: I don't know why, but at least on OS X, using Control + Backslash causes it to terminate and you get a "python crashed" dialog... strange. Not really that useful info, thus it is a comment!

Comment: Actually it works on all applications in Terminal...

Comment: David Beazley has described how a Ctrl/C interrupt can turn a muli-threaded Python script into a CPU hog.  It's touched on here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990102/python-global-interpreter-lock-gil-workaround-on-multi-core-systems-using-tasks) with a link to  Beazley's talk.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

On Windows, the only sure way is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Break</kbd>. Stops every python script instantly!

(Note that on some keyboards, "Break" is labeled as "Pause".)

Comment: What is `Break`? How do I type it?

Comment: There should be a Pause_Break button on your keyboard

Comment: What if there isn't? I'm on a Intel Macbook, and it doesn't have a very full-featured keyboard.

Comment: Ctrl+Break isn't working for me on Linux, neither does Ctrl+z mentioned below. The only thing that seems to work is pressing Ctrl+c rapidly until the command prompt shows up again.

Comment: On Linux you should use Ctrl-Shift-\

Comment: Ctrl + break not only kills the python script but also PowerShell

Comment: ctrl+Z doesn't kill the script, it just hides it to the background and suspends it. You can type fg to recall it.

Comment: I want to point out that ctrl+c does not **kill** the script, it **stops** the script, putting it in the shell's background, elaborated upon here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116959/there-are-stopped-jobs-on-bash-exit

Comment: `Ctrl+Fn+F6` or `Ctrl+Fn+S ` on Dell laptops without break key

Comment: if you don't have ctrl+break and nothing else works, fire up the on screen keyboard (start > run > `osk`), click on `ctrl` and then click on `scroll lock`.

Comment: On my HP Zbook I had to use Ctrl+fn+Pause

Comment: Dosent work for pygame programs because it handles it

Answer (score 113):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> while a python program is running will cause python to raise a [`KeyboardInterrupt`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt) exception.  It's likely that a program that makes lots of HTTP requests will have lots of exception handling code.  If the `except` part of the `try`-`except` block doesn't specify which exceptions it should catch, it will catch all exceptions including the `KeyboardInterrupt` that you just caused.  A properly coded python program will make use of the [python exception hierarchy](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) and only catch exceptions that are derived from `Exception`.

```
#This is the wrong way to do things
try:
  #Some stuff might raise an IO exception
except:
  #Code that ignores errors

#This is the right way to do things
try:
  #Some stuff might raise an IO exception
except Exception:
  #This won't catch KeyboardInterrupt
```

If you can't change the code (or need to kill the program so that your changes will take effect) then you can try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> rapidly.  The first of the `KeyboardInterrupt` exceptions will knock your program out of the `try` block and hopefully one of the later `KeyboardInterrupt` exceptions will be raised when the program is outside of a `try` block.

Comment: This is a great answer to enable the most common "break" which is ctrl+c.

Comment: Not for me. I have only a single `except KeyboardInterrupt` case and still it won't trigger, unless the application is waiting for user keyboard input. Windows completely ignores the Ctrl+C

Answer (score 58):

If it is running in the Python shell use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, otherwise locate the `python` process and kill it.

Comment: `^Z` --> `[1]+  Stopped ` --> `kill %1` to stop job #1 (or job %1 as bash puts it)

Comment: Worth adding to the answer that Ctrl+Z just *pauses* the process.

Comment: To elaborate on the above: Pausing the process keeps it around in memory and in your shell, it just prevents it from using CPU resources. Files, sockets, everything is still open and in use. In fact, typing `fg` will bring it right back.

Comment: `Ctrl+Z` is not the proper way to stop a python script and should be avoided unless you plan on resuming the paused process.

Comment: Ctrl+Z and Enter stop Python shell on Windows.

Answer (score 42):

The interrupt process is hardware and OS dependent. So you will have very different behavior depending on where you run your python script. For example, on Windows machines we have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (`SIGINT`) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> (`SIGBREAK`).

So while SIGINT is present on all systems and can be handled and caught, the SIGBREAK signal is Windows specific (and can be disabled in *CONFIG.SYS*) and is really handled by the BIOS as an interrupt vector [INT 1Bh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_call), which is why this key is much more powerful than any other. So if you're using some *nix flavored OS, you will get different results depending on the implementation, since that signal is not present there, but others are. In Linux you can check what signals are available to you by:

```
$ kill -l
 1) SIGHUP       2) SIGINT       3) SIGQUIT      4) SIGILL       5) SIGTRAP
 6) SIGABRT      7) SIGEMT       8) SIGFPE       9) SIGKILL     10) SIGBUS
11) SIGSEGV     12) SIGSYS      13) SIGPIPE     14) SIGALRM     15) SIGTERM
16) SIGURG      17) SIGSTOP     18) SIGTSTP     19) SIGCONT     20) SIGCHLD
21) SIGTTIN     22) SIGTTOU     23) SIGIO       24) SIGXCPU     25) SIGXFSZ
26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF     28) SIGWINCH    29) SIGPWR      30) SIGUSR1
31) SIGUSR2     32) SIGRTMAX
```

So if you want to catch the `CTRL+BREAK` [signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) on a linux system you'll have to check to what [POSIX signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) they have mapped that key. Popular mappings are:

```
CTRL+\     = SIGQUIT 
CTRL+D     = SIGQUIT
CTRL+C     = SIGINT
CTRL+Z     = SIGTSTOP 
CTRL+BREAK = SIGKILL or SIGTERM or SIGSTOP
```

In fact, many more functions are available under Linux, where the <kbd>SysRq</kbd> (System Request) key can take on [a life of its own](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)...

Answer (score 38):

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> Difference for Windows and Linux**

It turns out that as of Python 3.6, the Python interpreter handles <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> differently for Linux and Windows. For Linux, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> would work *mostly* as expected however on Windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> *mostly* doesn't work especially if Python is running blocking call such as `thread.join` or waiting on web response. It does work for `time.sleep`, however. Here's the [nice explanation](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-August/148800.html) of what is going on in Python interpreter. Note that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> generates `SIGINT`.

**Solution 1: Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> or Equivalent**

Use below keyboard shortcuts in terminal/console window which will generate `SIGBREAK` at lower level in OS and terminate the Python interpreter.

**Mac OS and Linux**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd></kbd></kbd>

**Windows**:

- General: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>
- Dell: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- Lenovo: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
- HP: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>
- Samsung: <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>

**Solution 2: Use Windows API**

Below are handy functions which will detect Windows and install custom handler for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+C in console:

```
#win_ctrl_c.py

import sys

def handler(a,b=None):
    sys.exit(1)
def install_handler():
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        import win32api
        win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(handler, True)
```

You can use above like this:

```
import threading
import time
import win_ctrl_c

# do something that will block
def work():
    time.sleep(10000)        
t = threading.Thread(target=work)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

#install handler
install_handler()

# now block
t.join()

#Ctrl+C works now!
```

**Solution 3: Polling method**

I don't prefer or recommend this method because it unnecessarily consumes processor and power negatively impacting the performance.

```py
    import threading
    import time

    def work():
        time.sleep(10000)        
    t = threading.Thread(target=work)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    while(True):
        t.join(0.1) #100ms ~ typical human response
    # you will get KeyboardIntrupt exception
```

Comment: No, on Ubuntu, for both python 2.7 and 3.6, pressing `ctrl + c` doesn't quit but showing `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Comment: I like the thread example, but you don't need to use the `SetConsoleCtrlHandler()`. You can just do a `try: time.sleep(5);except KeyboardInterrupt: break;` in a `while 1` loop. This works with any long delay for event handlers, but should be used with care when using polling and using not less time than: `time.sleep(0.01)`.

Comment: Thanks. However, solution 1 would require end user awareness, which they probably do not have (unless they came here and read this answer :-)  ). Solution 2 relies on platform specific API. I ended up using solution 3.

Comment: Ctrl+Fn+S worked for me, any idea how to configure this to be Ctrl+C?

Comment: What could be </kbd> ?

Answer (score 24):

This post is old but I recently ran into the same problem of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> not terminating Python scripts on Linux. I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> (`SIGQUIT`).

Comment: Although it will cause a core dump, but it did stops the script, thanks

Answer (score 14):

On Mac press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> to quit a python process attached to a terminal.

Comment: This is the only answer that works well for me on OSX in 2022

Comment: Verified, this works on Mac OSX in 2022. Other method although a bit longwinded also works: ctrl+z --> [1]+  Stopped  --> kill %1

Answer (score 8):

Capture the `KeyboardInterrupt` (which is launched by pressing `ctrl`+`c`) and force the exit:

```
from sys import exit

try:
    # Your code
    command = input('Type your command: ')

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # User interrupt the program with ctrl+c
    exit()
```

Answer (score 3):

On a mac / in Terminal:

1. Show Inspector (right click within the terminal window or Shell >Show Inspector)
2. click the Settings icon above "running processes"
3. choose from the list of options under "Signal Process Group" (Kill, terminate, interrupt, etc).

Answer (score 1):

- Forcing the program to close using Alt+F4 (shuts down current program)
- Spamming the X button on CMD for e.x.
- Taskmanager (first Windows+R and then "taskmgr") and then end the task.

Those may help.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, what killed the process on my Raspberry 3B+ (running raspbian) was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>. On my French AZERTY keyboard, the touch <kbd>'</kbd> is also number 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can open your task manager (ctrl + alt + delete, then go to task manager) and look through it for python and the server is called (for the example) _go_app (naming convention is: _language_app).

If I end the _go_app task it'll end the server, so going there in the browser will say it "unexpectedly ended", I also use git bash, and when I start a server, I cannot break out of the server in bash's shell with ctrl + c or ctrl + pause, but once you end the python task (the one using 63.7 mb) it'll break out of the server script in bash, and allow me to use the git bash shell. [image]

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, you use the good old <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. Note: it is the Ctrl key, not Command or Option key.

Answer (score 0):

The post is quite old but I faced the same issue this morning. On Mac OS, using `pgrep Python` to get the pid and then `kill [pid]` to kill the process worked fine.