# Exiting from python Command Line

Tags: python, command-line-interface

To exit from Python command line, I have to type exit(). If I type exit, it says

```
Use exit() or Ctrl-Z plus Return to exit
```

Usually when you type `exit`, you would want to exit the program. Why does the interpreter give me the above error when it knows I am trying to exit the command line? Why doesn't it just exit? I know it doesn't matter and its a silly question but I am curious.

Comment: It might have to do with how functions are often called with `()` at the end... otherwise, it might (possibly) be a variable... or some sort of object...

Comment: right but the interpreter knows that i'm trying to exit and thats why prints that message. otherwise it would have printed an error message. If it knows i'm trying to exit, it can just exit.

Comment: exit or exit() throws an error for me about 20% of installations I've found in the world...  Only CTRL+Z + return consistently works.

Comment: I think `exit` doesn't work with all python versions (`Ctrl-Z` on windows, `Ctrl-D` on Linux and `exit()` work with all python versions

Comment: I installed python on windows and ran into the same issue. "exit" does not work and even did not give me such hint. I also tried quit and [Ctrl][d] but nothing worked. Not even exit() or quit() is working. Hitting [Ctrl][z] followed by a [Return] did the job. However, with such a lousy UX I wonder why people actually end up using python - what a nightmare. All the answers trying to give arguments for this ugly behavior simply miss the point of UX.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In my python interpreter `exit` is actually a string and not a function -- `'Use Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit.'`. You can check on your interpreter by entering `type(exit)`

In active python what is happening is that exit is a function. If you do not call the function it will print out the string representation of the object. This is the default behaviour for any object returned. It's just that the designers thought people might try to type exit to exit the interpreter, so they made the string representation of the exit function a helpful message. You can check this behaviour by typing `str(exit)` or even `print exit`.

Comment: Ctrl-Z is what you do on Windows (well, DOS) where you would do Ctrl-D on Unix-like systems.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Ah, good to know. I have little experience of programming on windows.

Answer (score 76):

This works for me, best way to come out of python prompt.

```
exit()
```

Comment: I'm confused about this answer...the question itself says they already know that `exit()` works, and they want to know why `exit` without parens does not work.

So this answer just repeats part of the question and doesn't actually answer it.

Comment: I kind of want to downvote this answer for not reading the question, but I suppose for most python installations this is correct; it's just that the user said this doesn't work in their case, so recommending it seems... improper.

Comment: @kettlecrab who cares about the specifics of the original question, that is for one specific person. many of us type in related keywords and end up in threads like these where these kind of answers help us.

Answer (score 42):

When you type `exit` in the command line, it finds the variable with that name and calls `__repr__` (or `__str__`) on it. Usually, you'd get a result like:

```
<function exit at 0x00B97FB0>
```

But they decided to redefine that function for the `exit` object to display a helpful message instead. Whether or not that's a stupid behavior or not, is a subjective question, but one possible reason why it doesn't "just exit" is:

Suppose you're looking at some code in a debugger, for instance, and one of the objects references the `exit` function. When the debugger tries to call `__repr__` on that object to display that function to you, the program suddenly stops! That would be really unexpected, and the measures to counter that might complicate things further (for instance, even if you limit that behavior to the command line, what if you try to print some object that have `exit` as an attribute?)

Comment: In this case, the real exit function is not even in scope unless you `import sys`, after which you would call sys.exit() to exit the interpreter.

Answer (score 29):

With Anaconda 4.5+ and Python 3.6+ on Windows use

```
Ctrl+Z
```

or

```
exit()
```

In some cases, you might have to use

```
Ctrl+Break
```

If your computer doesn't have `Break` key then [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52941752/207661).

Answer (score 26):

I recommend you exit the Python interpreter with <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>.  This is the old ASCII code for end-of-file or end-of-transmission.

Comment: Seems like this method doesn't work if the script ran into an error.

Comment: `Ctrl-Break` works consistently in Windows. `Ctrl-D` or `Ctrl-Z` worked in Windows for Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.6. But in Python 3.7 these stopped working, and the shortest ASCII sequence that exits is `Ctrl-Z` `Enter`.

Comment: Ctrl-Break, Ctrl-D, Ctrl-Z, Ctrl-Z+Etner : none of them worked for me to terminate a simple python script from keep running on a shell's terminal. only when I close the shell itself. Why is it? I am running pyhton 3.7

Answer (score 21):

This message is the `__str__` attribute of `exit`

look at these examples :

1

```
>>> print exit
Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit
```

2

```
>>> exit.__str__()
'Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit'
```

3

```
>>> getattr(exit, '__str__')()
'Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit'
```

Answer (score 11):

Because the interpreter is not a shell where you provide commands, it's - well - an interpreter. The things that you give to it are Python code.

The syntax of Python is such that `exit`, by itself, cannot possibly be anything other than a name for an object. Simply referring to an object can't actually do anything (except what the read-eval-print loop normally does; i.e. display a string representation of the object).

Comment: 11 years later: theoretically, since the interpreter prints the string representation of the results that are calculated, the necessary logic could be put into the `__repr__` of the class that `exit` instantiates. However, this would cause surprising and inconsistent behaviour, especially when comparing what happens in a script vs. in the interpreter.

Answer (score 9):

You can fix that.

Link `PYTHONSTARTUP` to a python file with the following

```
# Make exit work as expected
type(exit).__repr__ = type(exit).__call__
```

---

How does this work?

The python command line is a read-evaluate-print-loop, that is when you type text it will read that text, evaluate it, and eventually print the result.

When you type `exit()` it evaluates to a callable object of type `site.Quitter` and calls its `__call__` function which exits the system. When you type `exit` it evaluates to the same callable object, without calling it the object is printed which in turn calls `__repr__` on the object.

We can take advantage of this by linking `__repr__` to `__call__` and thus get the expected behavior of exiting the system even when we type `exit` without parentheses.

Comment: They took the effort to make `exit` print the "helpful" string, but they couldn't just bind it to do the natural thing and exit the interpreter. Being forced to type the parentheses every time is frustrating. This answer is perfect and should be the accepted one instead.

Answer (score 5):

To exit from **Python terminal**, simply just do:

```
exit()
```

Please pay attention it's a function which called as most user mix it with exit without calling, but new Pyhton terminal show a message...

or as a shortcut, press:

```
Ctrl + D
```

on your keyboard...

[image: ctrl + D]

Comment: Everything you said has been covered in the answers above already.

Answer (score 0):

If you stuck in python command line and none of above solutions worked for you,
try `exit(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Very old post, but maybe useful to update it, for python 3.12 console command:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

Alternative, still working:

```
CTRL+Z and Enter
```

Answer (score -1):

"exit" is a valid variable name that can be used in your Python program. You wouldn't want to exit the interpreter when you're just trying to see the value of that variable.

Comment: Except if you assign to `exit`, you override this symbol, and `exit()` will no longer work. Although this symbol is a valid variable name, using it in such a way doesn't seem to be a very good practice.

Answer (score -2):

This UX in python:

```
$ python
Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> ^D
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    ♦
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'exit' is not defined
>>> quit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'quit' is not defined
>>> exit()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'exit' is not defined
>>> quit()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'quit' is not defined
```