# How to go back in the terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

I am new to using the terminal for Python. I was using MAC terminal and wrote

name = "name"
and then I typed dir(name)
I wanted to use help to see what title function does and hence wrote help(name.title). The screenshot shows what I get as output but I can't seem to exit this and go back to my old code anymore. Any help would be appreciated. Also, the people who use terminal for Python, how should I learn it? I am trying to get better at coding in my university holidays.

[image]
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exiting from python Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730409/exiting-from-python-command-line)

Comment: The terminal forgets the variable defined earlier. :(

Answer (score 1):

Did you try cmd+d or d in your terminal ?