# How to stop embedded R process in rpy2 using python/ipython

Tags: python, r, ipython, rpy2, sigint

I am using rpy2 to execute R from ipython. However I want to kill or stop the embedded R process but Ctrl-C is not working.

This is maybe because ipython intercepts SIGINT (I am not sure)..

I tested with SIGSTOP (Ctrl+Z) and it works..

Any method to terminate the embedded process (R/rpy2) without killing the ipython/python session?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364173/stopping-python-using-ctrlc/1364199#1364199

Answer (score 0):

When in Python, it is possible to interrupt R code with SIGINT (see [unitest with SIGINT in rpy2](https://bitbucket.org/lgautier/rpy2/src/591c54aeddc1ef0a69a48bbe921e1663e5e86d6a/rpy/rinterface/tests/test_EmbeddedR.py?at=default#cl-139)), to the extent that this R code is not a call to C not checking interruption signals (and in that case it would not be possible to interrupt the same code when in R).

I am unsure about what is happening with iPython.

Comment: I found [a new PR](https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/pull/832) (merged by you, right?). It would be better to update this answer after a new version is released (maybe 3.5.0), for people who is led to this question like me. :)