# How should I terminate long run scripts without any data generated, I tried pressing Ctrl+C in a windows console via paramiko module

Tags: python, linux, ssh, signals, paramiko

This is really interesting.
I have following scripts on my linux machine:

**sleep.py**

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.now())
time.sleep(20)
print('Over!')
print(datetime.now())
```

**loop.py**

```
import time
for i in range(20):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(i)
```

I can terminate them directly by `ctrl+c` if I login through PuTTY or git-bash.
But when I trying to run the Python scripts on Windows console:

**test.py**

```
def ssh_pty_command(cmd, ip, username, passwd=None, key_filename=None):
    """run ssh.exec_command with realtime output and return exit_code."""
    try:
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        logging.debug('Connecting to remote server {}...'.format(ip))
        ssh.connect(ip, 22, username, password=passwd,
                    key_filename=key_filename, timeout=5)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd, get_pty=True)
        logging.info('ssh_In: {}'.format(cmd))
        # print '$: {}'.format(cmd)
        for line in iter(stdout.readline, ""):
            logging.info('ssh_Out: {}'.format(
                line.rstrip('\n').encode('utf-8')))
        for err in iter(stderr.readline, ""):
            logging.error('ssh_Error: {}'.format(
                err.rstrip().encode('utf-8')))
        exit_code = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
        logging.debug('Task exit with code {}.\n'.format(exit_code))
        return exit_code
    except Exception as err:
        logging.error('*** Caught SSH exception: %s: %s' %
                      (err.__class__, err))
        raise
    finally:
        ssh.close()

  ssh_pty_command('python loop.py',ip,username)
  ssh_pty_command('python sleep.py',ip,username)
```

When I press `ctrl+c` , the `loop.py` terminated immediately, but the `sleep.py` waits until the `time.sleep(20)` is finished and then terminate the execution.
**How can I terminate the `sleep.py` immediately?**

**Note** I did try to use `get_pty=True` in my `exec_command` method in my function, but it didn't help.
I guess it should have something to do with the signal sent by Paramiko, but not sure where to dig in...

Comment: It's not really clear what do you do to terminate the commands. Do press Ctrl+C in the **local** Python console window?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, yes, that's what I do exactly! Sorry for the confusion, I find no where to edit my question again.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> signals an interrupt. Python interpreter checks for the interrupt regularly, and raises `KeyboardInterrupt` exception, when it detects one.

When Paramiko is waiting for an incoming data on a socket, the checking for interrupts is probably suspended (just guessing). So if a remote command is not producing any output, you cannot break the *local* script.

Your `loop.py` produces an output using `print(i)`, so your local Python script can be interrupted at the moment it's processing the output.

In any case, it's not the *remote* script that cannot be interrupted, it's the *local* script. So it has probably nothing to do with `time.sleep` as such.

See also:

- [Stopping python using ctrl+c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1364173/850848)
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt

---

If you actually do not want to wait for the command to finish, your question is not really about Python (nor Paramiko), but about Linux. See [Execute remote commands, completely detaching from the ssh connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30400/119732).

Comment: Oh man, you are right! When I delete the print(i) in loop.py, it also fails, it has nothing to do with time.sleep.

Comment: But the question remain the same, how can I terminate any long run script without data on a socket?

Comment: Try checking `.readable` before `.readline`, not to block the script, when there's no data (and sleep local script for a short period, when `!readable`).

Comment: The problem is that I don't have much control of the local scripts, it could be written by someone else. What I want to do is simply terminate the python scripts without waiting remotely via paramiko.

Comment: **But it's the local script that prevents the interruption!** You should not try to fix that from the remote script. You can of course hack it by producing sopme output (as your `loop.py` does). But that's just a hack in a response to a particular known behavior of the local script. - And note that you can use `Ctrl+Break` to forcefully terminate local script.

Comment: here is the story... the script may executing long time task which is in fact un needed if anything goes wrong already, and I tried to terminate the process as early as possible in my debugging environment.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand.

Comment: Well, I use python on my window machine to do some automated work on linux machine(I start some python scripts on the linux machine via this ssh.exec_command function ), for some reasons, I want to terminate the automated work directly, not waiting for the blocking code to be done. Thanks for your patient, I'm new to python and programming stuff, but I really tried a lot other method and need some guidance now.

Comment: Your question says *"how to terminate"*, not *"how to run script and not wait for it to finish"*. Anyway, if you do not want to wait, your question is not really about Python (nor Paramiko), but about Linux. See [Execute remote commands, completely detaching from the ssh connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30400/119732).