# Can I use multithreading to speed up my program limited by IO speed in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am very new to multithreading to Python and any other language, and I am trying to use multithreading to improve the speed of my program.

Basically, I have many large dataset, and my memory can only fit in 2 of them at the same time, so the solution I have in mind is to read a single dataset first, then load the second dataset while processing the first dataset using multithreading. In this way, I can save the time of waiting for the second dataset to get loaded. Does it work?

Comment: You may want to look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990102/python-global-interpreter-lock-gil-workaround-on-multi-core-systems-using-task), and also look into Python's global interpreter lock (GIL) and how it limits threading in applications. From the above link, this snippet seems relevant: _'But that this can seriously backfire on multi-core systems and you end up with IO intensive threads being heavily blocked by CPU intensive threads, the expense of context switching, the ctrl-C problem[*] and so on.'_

Comment: Are the files stored locally? Or are you pulling from a server?

Comment: Run benchmarks. If a second concurrent query significantly slows down the first query, you can save time with your approach.

Comment: You should use non-blocking I/O and an event loop instead of multithreading.  Or maybe two processes that alternate loading and processing data.  (If using Python 3.4 or higher is an option, you can use asyncio.)

Comment: There are some good PyCon videos - search for ```async```, ```await```, and ```concurrency```.  It should be fairly easy to set up a simple test to see if your process will benifit.